# Weirdly enough, '#' is a bad directive in format '%#H:%M'

Tags: python, datetime, format, strptime, strftime

I've seen a lot of similar questions, and still I don't seem to be able find out what the issue with my code is.
I'm running this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
date_st = "17:00"
date = datetime.strptime(date_st, "%#H:%M")
```

And I get the error:

```
ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format '%#H:%M'
```

I'm running Windows, that's why I use %#H and not %-H. I tried %-H though and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: [The following is a list of all the format codes that the 1989 C standard requires](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) Notice how `%#`  and `%-` is not listed.

Comment: Why do you think it's weird?  Does the Python documentation state that it should work?

Comment: @It_is_Chris well, so there is no way of removing trailing zeroes within the datetime's functionality?

Comment: What is your expected output based on your sample code i.e., what should `print(date)` return?

Comment: @It_is_Chris 0001-01-01 17:00:00. I also want it to work for not zero-padded strings, like "2:00"

Comment: @mykhailohoy did you mean `1900-01-01 17:00:00`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris oh. yes

Comment: @mykhailohoy then what is wrong with `print(datetime.strptime(date_st, "%H:%M"))`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris ok, I see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%#H` is only a valid formatting code for formatting a string ([`strftime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=msvc-170#generic-text-routine-mappings)), not parsing it with `strptime`.

I think `strptime` is provided by Python itself because windows doesn't have such a function, so theoretically support for `#H`/`-H` can be added. But since `%H` can already parse a single optional leading 0 for one-digit hours, there isn't much need for it (and POSIX `strptime` doesn't allow `%-H`).

You will have to do something else to parse it. In this case, something like:

```py
date_no_leading_zeros = date_st.lstrip("0")
# To support strings like "00:17" for 17 minutes past midnight
if date_no_leading_zeros.startswith(":"):
    date_no_leading_zeros = "0" + date_no_leading_zeros
date = datetime.strptime(date_no_leading_zeros, "%H:%M")
```

would work. But in other cases, you might want to use a regex to parse the date.

Comment: You may also be able to do thi swith zfill